# Get key name based on subkey value

Tags: json, key, jq

I'm trying to setup some monitoring.  As part of that I need to parse some gnarly json output to retrieve a node ID, which changes each time the node is rebooted or the service restarts.  I always know the node **name** but not the **"id"**.  The JSON looks something like this:

```
{
 "cluster_name":"cluster1",
 "nodes":
  {
   "generatednodeid1":{"name":"node01"},
   "generatednodeid2":{"name":"node2"}
  }
}
```

Doing `.nodes | keys` gives me **["generatednodeid1","generatednodeid2"]** as I'd expect.

I've tried `.nodes[] | select(.name=="node2")` but that only outputs **{"name":"node2"}**

What I really need to happen is if `.name=="node2"` then it gives me **generatednodeid2**

I've been beating my head against a wall.  I can't for the life of me figure out what I'm missing.  This seems so simple (probably is and I've looked at it too long).  Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Any ideas?

In this situation, the "to_entries" family of filters is helpful, e.g.:

```
.nodes
| to_entries[]
| select(.value.name == "node2")
| .key
```

Comment: That did it!  I tried that yesterday and couldn't get it to work.  But I think I just had the filters in the wrong order.  Like I said, staring at it too long!  Thank you so much!